# Jest - How to assert that all items in an array are objects and contain certain properties?

Tags: jestjs, automated-tests, integration-testing

I'd like to assert in `jest` that an array contains objects with certain properties, such as:

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'B' },
  { id: 3 }                 // should throw assertion error
]
```

In `chai` and `chai-things` I would do it with `should.all.have` and it's pretty self descriptive:

```
result.should.all.have.property('id');
result.should.all.have.property('name');
```

Is there a similar way to achieve this in `jest`?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `toHaveProperty` from Jest.

Here's the doc https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavepropertykeypath-value

```js
const elements = [
  { id: 1, name: 'A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'B' },
  { id: 3 }                 // should throw assertion error
]

elements.forEach(element => {
    expect(element).toHaveProperty('id')
    expect(element).toHaveProperty('name')
});
```

Comment: I actually ended up using the same implementation. I thought that it would be nice to have something built in (like the chai-things implementation above) but actually one forEach cycle is not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jest-extended:

```
const elements = [
 { id: 1, name: 'A' },
 { id: 2, name: 'B' }
]
expect(elements[0]).toContainAllKeys(['id', 'name']);
```

https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#tocontainallkeyskeys